# Quadratic system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, quadratics

I have a quadratic ODE system that looks like this: 
$\dot{x}=Ax+diag(x)Nx$ where $x \in R^n$ and $A,N \in R^{n \times n}$ and $diag(x) \in R^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix in which $x$ is its main diagonal. 
Is there a known solution to this system? Any hints, articles, papers or books about this kind of systems would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved the ODE $\dot{x} = A x + N x^2$
in the  $R^{1 \times 1}$ case ?
If not, I wouldn't even take a look at $R^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Yes, the first order case is simple to solve and it would be $x=\frac{ACe^{At}}{1-NCe^{At}}$ with $C=\frac{x_0}{A+Nx_0}$.

Comment: With my somewhat rusty knowledge, I get something slightly different: $x=\frac{ACe^{At}}{A-NCe^{At}}$ with $C=\frac{Ax_0}{A+Nx_0}$ .

Comment: BTW, did you try something too for the case $R^{2 \times 2}$ ?
If I understand the problem well, that would be the two equations $\;\dot{x_1}=A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+N_{11}x_1^2+N_{12}x_1x_2\;$ and $\;\dot{x_2}=A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+N_{21}x_1x_2+N_{22}x_2^2\;$ . Did you manage to solve these?

Comment: Thanks Han, Your solution is exactly the same of mine because you are using a different constant value, if you substitute your $C$ into your $x$ expression you would get my same expression of $x$. For the second order system yes it is right as you wrote it and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a _numerical solution_ of the system. Maybe some help can be found in the answers to another question: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569252/discretisation-of-ordinary-differential-equations-for-a-linear-filter-design

Comment: I am interested in an explicit solution because I need it for further use. Thanks for your try to help though.